# Does the forearm grip/handshake have a historical basis?

Tags: ancient-history, popular-culture

I was wondering where the **forearm handshake** came from. I found absolutely nothing in Wikipedia, so I have no idea if this is really historically based or just a recent popular greeting. I was led to believe that it may have been used by European pre-roman age tribes.

Comment: What is a "forearm handshake"?

Comment: I think he means the handshake you see sometimes in fantasy movies/TV shows where the two parties grasp each other's forearms. The only picture I could find online was [this one](http://d74bwl3dcueqd.cloudfront.net/images/guide/a8d39ae74d1a4d718214d7ab3dc0dbaa/315x500_ac.jpg)

Comment: Look up handshakes and recognitions for well-known secret societies. I cannot say more.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Well-known secrets? ;)

Comment: @MonsterTruck That is indeed exactly what the masons are. Conspiracy theorists think it's all some secret powerful organization, when it is in fact more reminiscent of [G.R.O.S.S.](http://calvinandhobbes.wikia.com/wiki/G.R.O.S.S.)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - perhaps the **societies** are well known, but their **secrets** are not... :-)

Comment: @Vector: **All** the secrets are well exposed on the web, and have been well published for over 100 years. One can readily find variations of hand-shakes like this in many places. I am simply not at liberty to say more.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - "not at liberty to say more"... understood... :-) Still " All the secrets are well exposed on the web" - can't agree with that. If they're secret, how would you know? What makes them secret is that they have **not** been exposed on the web etc... Consider the recent NSA business, it was secret for a long time - just recently become "exposed on the web". Who knows what else is yet to be exposed?

Comment: @Vector All the "secrets" of Scientology (that they charge you hundreds of thousands of dollars for) are on the Web, but Scientologists are prohibited from speaking about them or even reading about them before they have paid for the various levels of "Operating Thetan".

Comment: @EugeneSeidel - I will take that under advisement...

Answer (score 11):

The earliest reference I can find comes from a 1937 commentary on Shakespeare's "Julius Caesar", although there are many later references that this handshake was [taught to the actors](http://books.google.de/books?id=G5gLAQAAMAAJ&q=%22roman%20handshake%22&dq=%22roman%20handshake%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=C8g3UvvxKaWG4ATV3IG4Cw&redir_esc=y) by [Lawrence Alma-Tadema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_Alma-Tadema) in a 1898 staging of the play. It seems to have been often used in this play since, and I could find an [example](http://www.saintjohnshakespeare.ca/photos/handshake.jpg) from a 2005 staging.

Almost all references to it is from 2010 and later, which probably is because "cool" teenagers seldom go to watch Shakespeare in a theatre. So this handshake didn't become a "thing" until it popped up in TV and Movies. It seems it is the TV-series "[Spartacus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spartacus_%28TV_series%29)" we have to blame/thank for this.

However, there are no Roman era depictions of this handshake that I can find, and there are plenty of depictions of ordinary handshakes from the Roman era, so we have to conclude that it's attribution as a roman handshake is a later invention. That probably goes for the handshake itself as well, although that's less certain.

It's probably invented in the theatre to make the handshake look dramatic, and the prime suspect is Alma-Tadema himself, although this is pure conjecture.

Comment: Have you checked out secret-society handshakes and recognitions? They are known to date back to the 1700's at least.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Yes. I can't find any even remotely reliable-looking source claiming this is one of those.

Comment: @Vector: Ah, yes. No I meant that it's attribution as a Roman handshake was later. I'll clarify that. I doubt that the TV series picked it up from a youth subculture, it's more likely they have seen it in some other movie about Romans. Perhaps it was even in Spartacus the movie?

Comment: @Vector: Depends on what you mean with "old". Smells ancient? No. It smells exactly like 19th, possibly 18th century theatrical nonsense. Which is quite "old" of course. Theatrical does not in this case necessarily mean theatres, also indeed secret societies would engage in theatrics. Likewise the claim that it's to check for hidden weapons in the sleeve is a silly later invention. That's a *bad* place to have weapons.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10639/discussion-between-vector-and-lennart-regebro)

Comment: @LennartRegebro - +1 for excellent research and addressing the question head-on. But "It's probably invented in the theatre to make the handshake look dramatic, and the prime suspect is Alma-Tadema himself..." Your reference seems to indicate otherwise: "He taught the cast the wrist-group of the Roman Handshake" - the language indicates that there was already something known as the "The Roman Handshake" and Alma-Tadema simply taught it to the actors.

Comment: @Vector It just means Alma-Tadema called it a "Roman Handshake". That doesn't mean he didn't invent it.

Comment: @LennartRegebro - perhaps. But if so it probably should say "what he called the Roman Handshake"... anyhow, as you said, this is all pure conjecture.

Comment: The first time I saw a *dramatic* depiction of this was in the 1959 film of *Ben-Hur*.

Answer (score 5):

The [history section of the wikipedia article on handshakes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshake#History) suggests that the Greeks were familiar with the custom at least since the 5th century BC (because we have a sculpture showing Hera and Athena shaking hands that has been dated to the 5th century BC).

[image]
[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ACMA_1333_Samian_decree_2.JPG)

Romans also used handshake. It was depicted on Roman coins to symbolize agreement and compromise.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good answer as it goes, but has nothing whatsoever to say about the [forearm-grip handshake](http://d74bwl3dcueqd.cloudfront.net/images/guide/a8d39ae74d1a4d718214d7ab3dc0dbaa/315x500_ac.jpg) (the subject of the question)

Comment: If you change this answer to "The Romans used an ordinary handshake, so it's not Roman anyway" this would be a good answer, IMO.

Comment: The one person on the left in the relief seems to be a woman (look at chest and maybe the hair), so this may not be representative of a handshake which I have seen in movies about Roman soldiers greeting themselves.

Comment: @jjack the both are women.

Comment: @Anixx : both are goddesses, and watch your words if you don't want to endure their wrath.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two (not very good) references that attribute the ***forearm handshake*** to the Romans, if not earlier, along with other interesting background regarding the forearm handshake and similar variations on the common modern handshake:

- [**An Analysis of Handshake Styles**](http://westsidetoastmasters.com/resources/book_of_body_language/chap2.html)

Shaking hands is a relic of our ancient past. Whenever primitive tribes met under friendly conditions, they would hold their arms out with their palms exposed to show that no weapons were being held or concealed. **In Roman times, the practice of carrying a concealed dagger in the sleeve was common so for protection the Romans developed the Lower-Arm-Grasp as a common greeting.**

[image: Lower-Arm-Grasp]

***Lower-Arm-Grasp***

---

- [**LAKOTA COUNTRY TIMES - "Your handshake can say a lot", by Jim
  Kent**](http://www.lakotacountrytimes.com/news/2011-02-23/PDF/Page_015.pdf)

> I can recall being given instructions on “a proper handshake” by my
>   uncle as a skinny little kid growing up in Brooklyn. **I was told that
>   the custom dated back to Roman times - when men grasped not only one’s
>   hand, but the entire forearm to ensure that the person you were
>   greeting had no hidden weapons**. My interest in history, even at that
>   young age, re-enforced my understanding that this social expression
>   was something to be taken seriously. I pass on the instructions I
>   received any time a child or adolescent offers me a half-hearted
>   handshake. My wife is even more dedicated than I about such social
>   education. Over the years, I’ve heard the “hand-shake origin story”
>   shift to medieval times as well as ancient Egypt. Whatever the truth
>   behind the tale, the fact remains that the ritual has been around,
>   more or less, forever. **There have been variations on it -from the
>   “soul brother” clasp that began in the 60s, to the similar “brothers
>   in arms” grasp first used by many Vietnam vets, to the countless
>   adaptations created by diverse social groups**

*Unfortunately, these references don't bring reliable sources for their contentions, although I personally can attest to witnessing in NYC the variations cited by Jim Kent in the '60's and the Vietnam War era, and noting that they were new for that period. I always understood that such gestures are related to the gesture of reassuring or encouraging someone to be strong and stalwart by firmly grasping their arm or shoulder. The two parties exchange such a gesture, encouraging each other to be strong and united. This makes sense, given that this sort of greeting was particular to groups that considered themselves "comrades in arms", etc., and so perhaps this sort of thing hearkens back to some ancient form of warrior greeting. Admittedly though, this amounts to nothing more than interesting speculation.*

I suppose I can lay claim to being a "primary source" on such a thing, and IMO, when we encounter such forms of greeting today, they date back to those 1960's forms, just as do many other contemporary customs and fashions.

Comment: Hmmm. Any info on this "northern European 'handshake'" from your second quote?

Comment: @T.E.D.- You will have to inquire of Zhōnghuá Mínguó, Diplomat, Republic of China. If your interest is that strong, there apparently is such a person: Go to that page I referred to and look for "Byzantium Imperium", which links to a profile on that site - there is some contact info there.

Comment: @Vector: There is such a person, he is playing the Nation-states simulation game. The first reference is by how the website looks, older than 2010, maybe even the 90's. The second two are not. And they are definitely not before the 19th century... :-)

Comment: @LennartRegebro - LOL. I saw that it was a site about that game - didn't realize that he's talking about his country in the game! Reference removed.

Comment: I seem to have posed a really difficult question to validated with sufficient resources :-)... i'm not exactly sure what to believe here.

Comment: @AL13N - Regardless, in this case it means you've asked a very good question.

Comment: Seems odd that Romans carried knives in sleeves, since the toga and tunic didn't have long sleeves.  To kill Emperor Domitian, a servant had to fake an injury to get arm splints to conceal the weapon.

Comment: @Oldcat: Not so clear. Check [**Roman Togas - Images**](https://www.google.com/search?q=roman+toga&client=firefox-a&hs=GJj&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=vjqSU-2kCfffsATevYGABQ&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1280&bih=868). I would think it depended on the season and the situation, just like today, and also perhaps on one's station in life: A servant might not have sleeves, but a patrician or noble would have them.

Comment: @Vector - Cicero attacked Catiline's followers as the sort who would wear long sleeved tunics. Ceasar was mocked for wearing fringes at the end of his sleeves for a while.  Caesar's assassins kept the blades in the sinus of the toga (the pocket fold opposite the draped arm) not strapped to the wrist.

Comment: aren't sleeve daggers are carried in the LEFT sleeve (if you are right-handed)?

Comment: Roman tunics didn't have sleeves, and togas offered numerous folds in which to conceal a weapon.

Answer (score -2):

It's not European. It's African & Middle Eastern.
Prior to modern day plumbing. It was offensive to shake with the right hand. The right hand was/is used to clean ones self after secretion, so LEFT forearm shakes were done to avoid touching ones hand that was used to wipe themselves. Their a culture that respects hygiene. Not like here in the  States. Certain men & women are known to never wash their hands after urinating & defecating. NASTY!

Comment: Sources would improve this answers.

Comment: This is plain wrong. The bad hand is the left hand. Always use RIGHT hand in the Middle East.

Answer (score -2):

I have been taught that this form of handshake was brought about during the time of Vikings warriors would grab the forearm to prove and to feel for hidden daggers in case of assassination attempts...